# How do I differentiate types of XML files before deserializing?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, musicxml

I am loading MusicXML-files into my program. The problem: There are two “dialects”, *timewise* and *partwise*, which have different root-nodes (and a different structure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>
<!DOCTYPE score-partwise PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 2.0 Partwise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/partwise.dtd">
<score-partwise version="2.0">
    <work>...</work>
    ...
</score-partwise>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE score-timewise PUBLIC "-//Recordare//DTD MusicXML 2.0 Timewise//EN" "http://www.musicxml.org/dtds/timewise.dtd">
<score-timewise version="2.0">
   <work>...</work>
   ...
</score-timewise>
```

My code for deserializing the *partwise* score so far is:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ScorePartwise));
    var result = (ScorePartwise)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

What would be the best way to differentiate between the two dialects?

Comment: how big are the xml files?

Comment: That really depends on the piece, an average motet by Palestrina with four voices has about 12000 lines / 300 KB. A whole symphony will definitely have more than that.

Comment: Okay, I would load the 3rd line of the file into a string, and then do a `String.IndexOf()` to search for either partwise or timewise, then you know which type of file you are dealing with and can choose the correct serializer.

Comment: I don't know of many (any) score-timewise files out in nature, so one way most systems do it is just to assume score-partwise.  It may seem like a copout answer, but I think it's almost always what people do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by using an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse the file, read the root element to determine the type, and read it into your serializer.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
Type type;
if (xdoc.Root.Name.LocalName == "score-partwise")
    type = typeof(ScorePartwise);
else if (xdoc.Root.Name.LocalName == "score-timewise")
    type = typeof(ScoreTimewise);
else
    throw new Exception();
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
var result = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xdoc.CreateReader());
```

Comment: Loading the whole xml document just to check the first line will be somewhat slow considering the file is at minimum 12000 lines.

Comment: You're about to read the whole file by deserializing it anyway. Reading it -> check first line -> send in-memory file to deserializer can't be too bad (assuming memory usage isn't too bad; I'm assuming the file is in the tens of MB or less, which should be fine).

Answer (score 3):

I would create both serializers

```
var partwiseSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ScorePartwise));
var timewiseSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ScoreTimewise));
```

Assuming that there is only these two I would call **CanDeserialize** method on one

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
{
  using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filStream))
  {
    if (partwiseSerializer.CanDeserialize(xmlReader))
    {
       var result = partwiseSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
    else
    {
       var result = timewiseSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously this is just an idea how to do it. If there were more options or according to your application design I would use a more sophisticated way to call **CanDeserialize**, but that method is the key in my opinion:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize.aspx

The XmlReader class can be found here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlReader(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about resource usage:

```
    internal const string NodeStart = "<Error ";
    public static bool IsErrorDocument(string xml)
    {
        int headerLen = 1;
        if (xml.StartsWith(Constants.XMLHEADER_UTF8))
        {
            headerLen += Constants.XMLHEADER_UTF8.Length;
        }
        else if (xml.StartsWith(Constants.XMLHEADER_UTF16))
        {
            headerLen += Constants.XMLHEADER_UTF16.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (xml.Length < headerLen + NodeStart.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return xml.Substring(headerLen, NodeStart.Length) == NodeStart;
    }

internal class Constants
{
    public const string XMLHEADER_UTF16 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>";
    public const string XMLHEADER_UTF8 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
}
```